# Unable to log back into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I had an existing Windows 8 installation, alongside which I installed Ubuntu 14.04. A few months later my Windows 8 crashed and I simply formatted that partition and installed Windows 10 on that partition.

I could log into the Windows 10 OS and had just ensured basic functionality on it. After that I restarted, changed the BIOS boot order a little (so as to be able to log into Ubuntu, as otherwise I was getting forwarded directly to Windows 10). I was successful in logging into Ubuntu, but then I haven't been able to log back into Windows 10. The filesystem is unharmed, but I have run boot-repair 2 times.

The links generated are:

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/13651739/
- http://paste2.org/52JnfgMx

Also,

1. In the Grub menu I can see 2-3 Windows option. However, they point to the corrupted Windows 8 image I believe (which now no longer exists).
2. In the boot repair successfully repaired page, I am also getting a message stating that the boot files are far from the start of the disk and so my BIOS may not detect them.
3. My Windows 10 partition (earlier Windows 8 partition) was /dev/sda5 and my Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda10

Kindly help me boot into both Windows 10 as well as Ubuntu.

Comment: We will be able to help you boot Ubuntu, but Windows is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few comments about your setup generally and about dual-booting with Windows in particular:

- You say that you "haven't been able to log back into Windows 10," but it's *very* unclear what this means -- it could be that no Windows boot menu entries appear in GRUB, that selecting a Windows entry in GRUB causes the computer to crash, that Windows boots but won't accept your password, that your cat is clawing at you whenever you try to boot Windows, etc. Although some of those issues may be Linux/Ubuntu issues, others are better addressed to a Windows forum -- or to a vet ;-). In any event, if it's something GRUB-related, you should update your question with details. If it's more Windows-related, you should post on a Windows forum.
- Before you do anything potentially damaging, back up your ESP (`/boot/efi` under Ubuntu). Some potential repairs could make things worse -- maybe much worse. A file-level backup (using `cp`, `tar`, `zip`, or similar tools) should be fine.
- There's evidence of both BIOS-mode and EFI-mode boot loaders on your system. Such configurations are potential land mines. Please read [my page on the subject.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) In brief, I recommend *disabling* the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; also referred to as "legacy support" or similar terms) in your firmware. This will simplify your boot path and avoid potential mixed-mode problems.
- You ***MUST*** disable the *Windows* feature called "Fast Startup" (or various other things). This topic is covered [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) (among other places). Failure to disable this feature can cause data corruption on shared data partitions, including the EFI System Partition (ESP), which is where your boot loaders reside. Note that the *Windows* Fast Startup feature is unrelated to firmware features with similar names, like "fast boot." The latter can make it hard to boot an Ubuntu installer but are otherwise harmless to Ubuntu or to dual-boot configurations, provided you can get everything working initially. Of course, disabling this feature may be impossible if you can't boot to Windows; but if you can get in even temporarily, this should be the first thing you do.
- Some of your GRUB Windows entries point to the Windows boot loader under names created by Boot Repair's more intrusive (and usually unnecessary) options. Based on your `efibootmgr` output, it looks like these intrusive options were unnecessary. You may want to run Boot Repair again, enter the Advanced screen, select the option to restore backups, and continue. This may clean things up a bit. OTOH, it could make matters worse -- this is one situation where an ESP backup may become vital.
- You might want to try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can download a version for CD-R or USB flash drive (see the [downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)) and try rEFInd risk-free -- although you'll need to temporarily disable Secure Boot to try it this way. (You can re-enable Secure Boot and install rEFInd to your hard disk from your regular boot if you like it.) It's conceivable that rEFInd will get Windows booting again, but I can make no promises of that. With the tangle of backup boot loaders created by Boot Repair, the rEFInd menu is likely to be overpopulated at first, but you can trim it back in various ways.